# How can I add a generated Source Folder to my Source Path in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, annotation-processing

I use annotation processing. Therefore I use the [apt plugin](https://github.com/Jimdo/gradle-apt-plugin). It generates new java sources in `build/source/apt`.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'apt'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'gwt'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

eclipse {
    classpath {
       downloadSources=true
       downloadJavadoc=true
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'      
        classpath 'com.jimdo.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.5-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT:jar-with-dependencies'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-gwt:18.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'   
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.7.0'
    logLevel = 'INFO'
    minHeapSize = "512M";
    maxHeapSize = "1024M";


    compiler {
        strict = true;
    }
    modules 'test.GWTT'     
}

tasks.withType(de.richsource.gradle.plugins.gwt.AbstractGwtActionTask) {
    args '-XjsInteropMode', 'JS'
}
```

**I need this sources to be available in my project such that eclipse can find them and such that they are included while compiling the project how can I do that?**

Edit: Using

```
sourceSets {
    apt{
        java{
            srcDir 'build/source/apt'
        }
    }
}
```

Leads to the following errors when running `gradle build`:

```
Compiling module test.GWTT
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'test.client.GWTT'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TestGradle2/src/main/java/test/client/GWTT.java'
         [ERROR] Line 17: No source code is available for type test.client.test2.Dagger_MyWidgetGinjector; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Finding entry point classes
      Tracing compile failure path for type 'test.client.GWTT'
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TestGradle2/src/main/java/test/client/GWTT.java'
            [ERROR] Line 17: No source code is available for type test.client.test2.Dagger_MyWidgetGinjector; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
:compileGwt FAILED
```

Using the former Eclipse finds the sources of the generated files but build does not.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer here if any were helpful.

Answer (score 41):

What others answered overwrites my original directories, so I found a workaround - if you don't want to overwrite the original directory list, you can do it like this:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += myDir
sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs += myDir
```

The key is to use `+=` here. It's essentially the same as stating it like this:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java.srcDirs += myDir
    kotlin.srcDirs += myDir
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

`sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['build/generated-sources/xjc','src/main/java']` worked for me.

Comment: The solution does not scale. If you have multiple source directories they all need to be added here in this one line. The solution from milosmns addresses this shortcoming.

Answer (score 16):

Just in case somebody is searching for the solution using kotlin script (.kts):

```
sourceSets["main"].java.srcDir(file("path/to/generated/source/directory"))
```

Hope, it will help.

Comment: If you are already in the `val set by getting {}` block then you can just do `kotlin.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/source/path/to/my/dir")`

Comment: If you are not in the right place, you can get it off the project: `project.extensions.findByType(AppExtension::class.java)!!.sourceSets["main"].java.srcDir(file("path/to/generated/source/directory"))` :-)

Answer (score 8):

For dagger 2 with jar plugin you can put

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['build/generated/source/apt/main','src/main/java']
```

in the build.gradle

Comment: The solution does not scale. If you have multiple source directories they all need to be added here in this one line. The solution from milosmns addresses this shortcoming.

Answer (score 6):

Try defining a custom source set for the output classes.
Something like:

```
sourceSets {
    apt{
        java{
            srcDir 'build/source/apt'
        }
    }
}
```

should get you close.  For more detail check the source sets section (23.7) of the [java gradle plugin docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) for more detail.

Comment: Please see my edit I tried your idea. Eclipse found the sources but ``gradle build``leads to the error above and does not find the source.

Comment: Notbeing familiar with your code, is the error because the tests can't find the apt output?  If so then you probably need to hook that into your dependency graph.  Section 23.7.3 of the docs I posted have samples showing how to do that.  Good Luck.

Comment: I do not use any tests. the GWT plugin was not able to find the sources generated by the APT plugin. Do you know a way to tell the GWT plugin where the sources are?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin.  Does it hook directly into the java plugin?  if so you might need to explicitly provide those in the custom source set too.

Comment: Well I don't know here is the plugin: https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin. If you could post what you wrote in your last comment, then I can try it.

Comment: As I say, I'm not familiar with the gwt plugin.  Did you try adding the output of the apt source set as a dependency?

Comment: No I did not how can I add the output as a dependency?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70318/discussion-between-jaimie-whiteside-and-confile).

Answer (score 6):

Consider code structure like this

```
src
├───main
│   ├───gen
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───java
│   │           └───generated
│   │               └───code
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───java
│   │           └───test
│   └───resources
│       ├───icons
│       └───META-INF
└───test
    ├───java
    └───resources
```

> src/main/gen - is folder for generated code

> src/main/java - is folder for manuall code

To include both (generated and manuall java code) you have to specify both as input dirs for java compilation (in build.gradle file) - I've add it to the end of file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/gen']
        }
    }
}
```

You can specify as many sources as you want.
Hope this helps and explains a bit

Comment: I was going a bit crazy trying to figure this out because I had in my gradle.build already
java { srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/generated"]}

but intellij would not recognize the sources in src/main/generated. However if I change it to 'src/generated' like in your post, it suddenly works. Java dir still needs the main in the path or it wont work though

Answer (score 1):

When using kotlin gradle dsl:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("$apiSpecOutputDir/src/main/java")
        }
    }   
}
```